# How to dynamically create a class inside another class and add inheritance to it?

Tags: ruby

other SO answers shows how to create classes with inheritance, yes,
but i also need it to be a subclass of another class.

```
class Wall
  def initialize
    # i need a Brick class here with inheritance from Stone
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
class Stone

end

class Wall
    def initialize
        brick = Class.new Stone
        self.class.const_set :Brick, brick
    end
end

puts 'before initialize'
p Wall.constants
p Wall::Brick.ancestors rescue nil

puts 'after initialize'
Wall.new
p Wall.constants
p Wall::Brick.ancestors
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?file=how-to-dynamically-create-a-class-inside-another-class-and-add-inheritance-to-it.rb&lang=ruby&run=true)

Comment: Worked like a charm! my tutor will be happy tonight :) i can now recall he was speaking about `const_set` :) thank you!